# Chat server in Python

Tags: python, sql, server

I just need to know if it's decent or not.

[Project home](https://github.com/chatango-kotarou/HCS)

```
import glob
import tornado
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
class server(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def on_message(self, message):
        self.modDirectory = 'modules/*.py'
        self.files = glob.glob(self.modDirectory)
    #print(self.files)
        #CALL ON INIT
    self.modules = dict()
        self.commands = list()
    self.msg = dict()
    self.ip = self.request.remote_ip
    self.uip = {}
        self.loadModules()
        data = message.split(':', 1)
        if len(data) == 1:
            cmd, args = data[0]
        else:
            cmd, args = data
        key = cmd
        self.getCommand(cmd)
        cmd = self.getCommand(key)
        if cmd:
            if cmd:
                cmd.check(self, args)
    def loadModules(self):
        '''
        load modules that are found in self.files>glob.glob('directory/*.py')
        '''
    self.modules = {}
    self.commands = []
        for f in self.files:
        execfile(f, self.modules)
    for key, value in self.modules.items():
       if key == 'init':
        value(self)
    def callProtocal(self, evt):
        '''
        sends the protocals
        '''
    self.write_message(evt)
    def clearCommands(self):
        '''
        clears protocal list
        '''
        self.commands = list()
    def addCommand(self, *args, **kw):
        '''
        add the protocal to the list protocal>description>function>id
        '''
        co = Command(*args, **kw)
        self.commands.append(co)
    def getCommand(self, name):
        '''
        search for the protocal then returns the result
        '''
        name = name.lower()
        for command in self.commands:
            if command.name == name:
                return command
    return None
class Command(object):
        def __init__(self, name, desc, func, number = 0):
            self.name = name
            self.desc = desc
            self.number = int(number)
            self.func = func

        def run(self, mgr, args):

            if not args: return False
            else: return True
        def check(self, mgr, args):
            if not self.run(mgr, args): return
            else: self.func(mgr, args)
if __name__=="__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r'/', server)])
    __SERVER__ = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    __SERVER__.listen(address='localhost', port=6444)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**mod.py**

```
from db import database as self
from time import time
def init(mgr):
    mgr.addCommand('delMsg', 'delete a message', delMsg, 3)
    mgr.addCommand('delUserMsg', 'delete a users messages', delUserMsg, 4)
    mgr.addCommand('addMod', 'add a moderator', addMod, 5)
    mgr.addCommand('removeMod', 'remove a mod', removeMod, 6)
    mgr.addCommand('banUser', 'ban a user', banUser, 7)
    mgr.addCommand('unbanUser', 'unban a user', unBan, 8)

def delMsg(mgr, args):
    room = args[0]
    msgid = args[1]
        self.delMsg(room, msgid)
        mgr.callProtocal('msgremove:%s:%s:%s' % (room, msgid, time()))
def delUserMsg(mgr, args):
    room = args[0]
    user = args[1]
        self.delUserMsg(room, user)
        mgr.callProtocal('usermsgremove:%s:%s:%s' % (room, user, time()))
def addMod(mgr, args):
    room = args[0]
    user = args[1]
        self.addMod(room, user)
        mgr.callProtocal('mod:%s:%s:%s' % (room, user, time()))
def removeMod(mgr, args):
    room = args[0]
    user = args[1]
        self.removeMod(room, user)
        mgr.callProtocal('demod:%s:%s:%s' % (room, user, time()))
def banUser(mgr, args):
    room = args[0]
    user = args[1]
    target = args[2]
        self.banUser(room, user, target)
        mgr.callProtocal('banned:%s:%s:%s:%s' % (room, user, target, time()))
def unbanUser(mgr, args):
    room = args[0]
    user = args[1]
    target = args[2]
        self.unbanUser(room, user, target)
        mgr.callProtocal('unbanned:%s:%s:%s:%s' % (room, user, target, time()))
```

**room.py**

```
from db import database as self
import random
def init(mgr):
    mgr.addCommand('bmsg', 'send a message to the room', message, number=1)
    mgr.addCommand('bauth', 'login', login, number=2)
def message(mgr, args):
    if self.isConnected(args[1]):
        user = args[1]
        room = args[2]
    if self.getRoom(room) != False:
            msg = args[3]
            _ip = self.ip(self.uid(user))
            params = "b:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s" % (user, room, msg, _ip, self.uid(user))
            mgr.callProtocal(params + '<br />')
    else:
        mgr.callProtocal('NROOM:NO ROOM FOUND')
    else:
        mgr.callProtocal('NROOM:NO ROOM FOUND')
        mgr.callProtocal('NT_CONNECTED:%s' % ('YOU ARE NOT SIGNED IN'))
def login(mgr, args):
    status =args[0]
    if status == 'bauth':
        room = args[1]
        usern = args[2]
        password = args[3]
        st = self.check(usern, password)
        if st == 'ok':
            id = self.uid(usern)
            conip = mgr.ip
            self.setConnected(usern, mgr.ip, room)
            _ip = self.ip(id)
            mgr.callProtocal('LGN_OK:%s:%s:%s:%s' % (room, usern, id, _ip))
        elif st == 'denied':
            anonid = mgr.setSsid(ip=_ip, room=room) 
            user = 'anon%s' % anonid
            self.setConnected(user, mgr.ip, room)
            mgr.callProtocal('LGN_DENIED:%s:%s' % (user, _ip))
    if status == 'blogAnon' and not self.getRoom(room) == False:
        anonid = random.randrange(1000, 9000)
                self.setSsid(_ip, anonid)
                user = 'anon%i' % anonid
                self.setAnon(user ,_ip)
                mgr.callProtocal('anon_login:%s:%s' % (user, _ip))
```

**database.py**

```
import time
import mid
import uid
import hashlib
import sqlite3 as m

global db

dbType = "sqlite"
if dbType == "sqlite": 
    db = m.connect('CHAT.sqlite3')
elif dbType == "mysql":
    import MySQLdb as sql
    host = ""
    user = ""
    password = ""
    dbname = ""
    db = sql.connect(host, user, password, dbname)

cur = db.cursor()

def ip(id, ip, mode='id'):
    try:
        cur.execute('select * from ip where id like("%s")' % (id))
        ip = ''.join([i[1] for i in cur.fetchall()])
        return ip
    except:
                ssid = ip.replace('anon', '')
                cur.execute('select * from ssid where like("%s")' % ssid)
                ip = ''.join([i[2] for i in cur.fetchall()])
                return ip

def setIp(id, ip):
    try:
        cur.execute('delete from ip where id like("%s")' %(id))
        cur.execute('insert into ip(id, ip) values("%s", "%s")' % (id, ip))
        db.commit()
    except:
        cur.execute('insert into ip(id, ip) values("%s", "%s")' % (id, ip))
                db.commit()
def setSsid(room, ip):
    sid = random.randrange(1000, 9000)
    try:
        cur.execute('select room, ssid from ssid room="%s", ssid="%s"' % (room, str(sid)))
        ssid = [ssid[1] for ssid in cur.fetchall()]
        if str(sid) in ssid:
            while True:
                r = random.randrange(1000, 9000)
                if r not in ssid:
                    cur.execute('insert into ssid(ssid, room, ip) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (r, room, ip))
                            db.commit()
                    return r
                    break
    except:
        cur.execute('insert into ssid(ssid, room, ip) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (r, room, ip))
                db.commit()
        return str(sid)

def setConnected(user, ip, room):
    try:
                cur.execute('delete from connected where room="%s", user="%s"' %(room, user))
                cur.execute('insert into connected(user, ip) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (user, ip, room))
                db.commit()
        except:
                cur.execute('insert into connected(user, ip) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (user, ip, room))
                db.commit()
def getConnected(room, user):
    try:
         cur.execute('select room, user from connected where room="%s", user="%s"' % (room, user))
                 user = ''.join([i[0] for i in cur.fetchall()])
                 return True
    except: return False
def setMessage(room, user, msg):
        userid = UID(user)
        ip = ip(userid)
    msgid = mid.generate()
    cur.execute('insert into messages(room, user, message, msgid, userid, ip) values("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (room, user, msg, userid, ip))
        db.commit()
def getMessage(user):
        cur.execute('select room, user from messages user="%s"' % user)
        lis = [a[0:] for a in cur.fetchall()]
        return lis
def delMsg(room, msgid):
        cur.execute('delete from messages where room="%s" msgid="%s"' %(room, msgid))
        db.commit()
def delUserMsg(room, user):
        cur.execute('delete from messages where room="%s", user="%s"' %(room, msgid))
        db.commit()

def banUser(room, user, target):
        tid = UID(target)
    try:
        cur.execute('delete from banlist where room="%s", user="%s", target="%s", id="%s", ip="%s"' % (room, user, target, tid, ip))
                cur.execute('insert into banlist(room, user, target, tid, ip, time) values("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (user, target, tid, ip, time.time()))
                db.commit()
        except:
        cur.execute('insert into banlist(room, user, target, tid, ip, time) values("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % (user, target, tid, ip, time.time()))
                db.commit()
def unbanUser(room, user, target):
        if UID(target) == 'ip':
                ip = ip(user, mode = 'user')
    try:
        cur.execute('delete from banlist where room="%s", user="%s", target="%s", id="%s", ip="%s"' % (room, user, target, tid, ip))
        db.commit()
    except: pass
def getRoomOwner(room):
        cur.execute('select * from rooms where room="%s"' % room)
        owner = ''.join([n[1] for n in cur.fetchall()])
        return owner
def getBanlist(room):
    cur.execute('select * from banlist room="%s"' % room)
    l = [a[1] for a in cur.fetchall()]
    return l
def addMod(room, user):
     try:
                cur.execute('delete from mods where room="%s", user="%s"' % (room, user))
        cur.execute('insert into mods(room, user, userid) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (room, user, time.time()))
                db.commit()
         except:
                cur.execute('insert into mods(room, user, userid) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (room, user, time.time()))
                db.commit()
def removeMod(room, user):
     try:
        cur.execute('delete from mods where room="%s", user="%s"' % (room, user))
        db.commit()
     except:
        return False

def register(user, password):
    cur.execute('insert into register(user, password userid, time) values("%s", "%s", "%s")' % (user, hashlib(password).hexdigest(),  uid.generate(), time.time()))
    db.commit()
def UID(user):
    cur.execute('select * from register where user like("%s")' % user)
    Uid = ''.join([n[2] for n in cur.fetchall()])
    return Uid
def check(user, password):
    cur.execute('select * from register where user like("%s")' % user)
    auth = ''.join([n[1] for n in cur.fetchall()])
    if hashlib(password).hexdigest == auth: return 'ok'
    else: return 'denied'
def getMods(room):
    cur.execute('select * from mods where room like("%s")' % mods)
    l = [i[1] for i in cur.fetchall()]
    return l
def getRoom(room, check = True):
    cur.execute('select * from rooms where room like("%s")' % room)
    r = ''.join([n[0] for n in cur.fechall()])
    if check == True:
        if r == room: return True
        elif r != room: return False
    elif check == False:
        return room
```

Comment: Please double-check your indentation. It looks like you have mingled tabs and spaces in your code, which is a bad idea, especially in Python — and now you can see why.

Answer (score 4):

> I just need to know if it's decent or not.

Well, it's not.

- You're not following [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide
- You have spaces mixed with tabs, which can lead to nasty bugs that will really hurt you

The code is buggy and strange in many places.

---

> ```
> def on_message(self, message):
>     self.modDirectory = 'modules/*.py'
>     self.files = glob.glob(self.modDirectory)
> ```

The variable is called `modDirectory`, but its value is a glob. That's misleading. But the bigger problem is that `modDirectory` is an instance variable, but it's not used anywhere else in the posted code. This is better:

```
self.files = glob.glob('modules/*.py')
```

---

There is a bug here:

> ```
> data = message.split(':', 1)
> if len(data) == 1:
>     cmd, args = data[0]
> ```

This assignment won't work, you'll get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

---

What is going on here?

> ```
> self.getCommand(cmd)
> cmd = self.getCommand(key)
> ```

First you call `self.getCommand` and throw away the result? It's not clear what you're doing here and why. If the first call is necessary, that would mean that `self.getCommand` has side effects, which is a bad practice in general, especially for something that looks like a getter.

---

What's going on here:

> ```
> if cmd:
>     if cmd:
> ```

---

At this point I stopped reviewing. This is just too messy and far from decent. I bet you could spot these things yourself if you give it a careful read!

Here's what you can do to improve this, very easily:

1. Install `pep8` (`pip install pep8`). It's a command line tool that verifies specified file or an entire directory tree for PEP8 violations. As much as possible, follow it and fix everything it tells you.
2. Install `pyflakes` (`pip install pyflakes`). Another command line tool, that checks for common mistakes in Python coding practices. Use it the same way as the `pep8` tool.

If you use these tools to clean up your code and post again a new question, that will have a LOT better chance of being decent!

Comment: Now that you point it out. I did do some needless things. As  for indents its just how it pasted. But I should start using py 3 so I stop being lazy with tab/spaces. Considering py 3 is strict on that. Now the `if cmd` I didn't notice until now. I should also point out the valueError you mentioned I just forgot to add quotes as the second param.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really comment on the python, but I see a couple issues with your SQL.

Firstly, you should really avoid using `SELECT * FROM XYZ`, you should always try to just return the columns you need. It makes it easier to understand what is actually happening and can speed up queries, it's pretty much a win-win.

Secondly, SQL is typically written with keywords such as `SELECT` or `DELETE` in uppercase.

Comment: My SQL knowledge is limited, but I do see what you mean in some cases. As for the caps I know its good practice to do them in caps, that's what company's look for. But considering this was a spare time project I thought it really didn't matter. I did put it on github so I should of fixed all this to make it look professional.

Comment: @user3103366 that's an odd attitude, particularly from someone who's submitting to code review. You don't try to write good code just because *"that's what company's [sic] look for"* or *"to make it look professional"*. You do it because it makes it easier for you and others to read, because it helps make you a better programmer, and because it gives you the feeling that you've created something good. The standards still apply for personal projects; you should aspire to write clean, readable code *all of the time*.